# How to add dynamicly linked and created pages in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, dynamic

Since I had some comments on the formulation of my question, I decided to rewrite it completely. And also, I understand a little bit more about wordpress so it should make more sense now.

So, let's start with what I'm trying to accomplish by using a simple example:

---

**Goal**:

Make a search engine for some products and link to them using a database to generate the information.

**Result**:

```
http://my.site.url/wordpress/<plugin-name>  <-- The page with the "search" and "search result
http://my.site.url/wordpress/<plugin-name>/products/<product_name>  <-- When click on a search result
```

---

**Part 1**:

I want to make a plugin with the name "plugin-name" Right now, I put my code in

```
http://my.site.url/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/<plugin-name>
```

On the activate, I create some tables with some data. Since there is no page yet, I create 1 on the fly using the API call 'wp_insert_post'. I give the name and slug "myPlugin".

So, when I go on the main site, I can see my newly created page "myPlugin". But right now, there is no content attached to it. To do so, from what I understand, I need to create a page in my plug-in directory named "myPlugin.php".

```
http://my.site.url/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/<plugin-name>/myPlugin.php
```

So, how do I link the page I created manually and the source file in the plugin directory?

---

**Part 2**

When clicking on a link in the search result, I would like to have a page "product.php" and display its information. So, is it possible to create a "temporary url" for the result using sub pages (see result at the beginning)? And if possible, how can we achieve that?

---

Thanks in advance and I hope it's clearer.

Comment: You want a page to render as if it was part of your wordpress site but not created using the Page's mode from the control panel? You should clarify your needs, right now it's a cluster of nonsense for me.

Comment: It makes sense to me :) Yes I want the pages render as if it were part of the wordpress page, or else I wouldn't have to ask those questions. I want to use the "wordpress API".

Comment: @thisMayhem Just added some clarifications. Hope it helps to understand better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

u can find how to create plugin from 
http://ditio.net/2007/08/09/how-to-create-wordpress-plugin-from-a-scratch/

in plugin write function for search(as per u r logic) fetch result

create a custom page refer video from www.wordpressmax.com/customize-wordpress/custom-page

in custom pages template in between get_header(); and get_footer(); call search function and display records.

Thats it.

Comment: I already found the first tutorial, but how to create a custom page is what I was missing. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

thisMayhem is right. This sounds like a bunch of nonsense. But, if you're trying to make a WP page that executes some custom PHP, look up the WP template hierarchy.

What you can do is this:

- create a WP "page" - call it "Search results."
- create a template directory file called page-search-results.php (filename corresponds with slug of page from step 1)
- put some generic header/footer stuff there (see other template files - most often it's just a question of putting in `<?php get_header(); ?>` and `<?php get_footer(); ?>`)
- put PHP code in that thar page. in them hills.
- if you use a caching plugin, may want to put an exemption for /search-results/

So, when someone pulls up http://your.site/search-results/ - your custom PHP code will execute. It's up to you to make that logic and communication happen - whether via $_GET or $_POST, etc.

Comment: I just updated my post in order to be more precise now that I understand a little bit more. I hope it looks a little less rubbish. With your answer, I still don't get it how to link the page-search-results.php in my plugin directory with the WP Page. The file just get ignored. Maybe I need some kind of AddAction?

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry you're experiencing some problems. Unfortunately as we say above because it's a 'one off' for a client project we can't support it - it works for them :) Feel free to rip it apart and retest and if you have any success let us know.